# Updating Fields sequentially based on conditions

Tags: sqlite

I have this current example data set

```
 NEW_ID Name    OLD_ID  New_Name
    123 Hello   XYZ 
    124 How     XYZ 
    125 Are     XYZ 
    126 My      ABC 
    127 Name    ABC 
    128 Is      ABC 
    129 Alex    ABC
```

My objective is to amend the Name field to a new naming convention to be stored in New_Name- ie Hello_Part_1, How_Part_2, Are_Part_3 where all these records share an OLD_ID - in this case XYZ. Similarly, with My_Part_1, Name_Part_2, Is_Part_3, Alex_Part_4 etc with IDs that equal ABC.

I'm using SQL Lite with an Import of .CSV File.

The naming convention is as follows - NAME_PART_X where X increments on the number of records within that 'Group' of OLD_IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not work sequentially; you have to express the operation independently for each row.

The number you want is the count of rows with the same old ID that also have a new ID that is the same or smaller as the new ID of the current row.
This can be computed with a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET New_Name = Name || '_Part_' ||
               (SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM MyTable AS T2
                WHERE T2.OLD_ID  = MyTable.OLD_ID
                  AND T2.NEW_ID <= MyTable.NEW_ID);
```